# How to create a view/list/report that auto populates based on a dropdown menu of choices on a SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: list, list-view, sharepoint-on-prem

This is my first post and has most likely been covered, So forgive me if this has already been answered. I couldn't find anything specific to my issue.

I have a SharePoint 2013 Server `On-premise` site with details for over 150 customers each within their own respective sites within the site collection. I would like the users to have the ability to select from a drop-down menu a set of choices and then have a view that auto populates the results based on their selection.  For example, the drop-down menu would consist of Account Type:

```
Account Type/ Login Name/ URL
```

```
Domain        wsmith     domain.org
```

```
Adobe         cdavis     adobe.com
```

When they select **"Domain"** from account type, only the **Login Name** and **URL** for Domain will show in the results. Alternatively, when they select **"Adobe"** from a list of choices, they will see the Login Name and URL for Adobe; in my example cdavis and adobe.com etc.

Additionally, the information that will auto populate is different for all 150 customers. I have exported an `Excel` spreadsheet to a SharePoint `list` that consists of all the data I am needing for all 150+ customers (If it helps). But I am not sure of how to best approach this problem without having to do this for every individual site within SharePoint. Therefore, my problem is twofold:

How do I create the dropdown menu of choices to auto populate on the site page?

Secondly, how can I achieve the give results without having to edit each individual customer site?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If all your data is in a single list and you want to filter based on one column, you can have the list displayed through a list view webpart in a page and connect it to a filter webpart on the same page. This should be fairly easy as you can import your data from the spreadsheet that you have already prepared.

If this information is in a list in each of the different customer site, there should be a common factor that connects all of these lists, like a common content type.

In that case you can create a content query webpart or even a html/js based solution to query the data based on a given filter.